# Stone Cech compactification of the naturals a cts image of the Cantor set?

Tags: general-topology

Is $\beta \mathbb{N}$, the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{N}$, a continuous image of the Cantor set?

Comment: A continuous image of a sequentially compact space is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Cantor set is sequentially compact, since compactness is equivalent to sequential compactness for metrizable spaces. If $\beta \mathbb{N}$ were a continuous image of it, then it would be sequentially compact too (an easy exercise in point-set topology), but as is quite well known, this is not the case.

Answer (score 18):

The Cantor set has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$, and the Stone–Čech compactification of the integers has cardinality $2^{\mathfrak{c}}$.  Hence there is no surjective map from the Cantor set to $\beta\mathbb N$.

Comment: thanks! nice argument too.

Answer (score 10):

A Hausdorff space is the continuous image of the Cantor set iff it is compact metrisable.